# How to deploy a web application in Netty server

Tags: web-services, angular, netty

Hi I am new in learning netty, wanted to deploy a Angular2 based web application on netty server.
Why we use netty server why it is different from tomcat application server.
Please help me with tutorials. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netty is not a web server/application server, but an IO framework which can be used to build webservers, or any high-performant IO applications.

If you really want to use netty, you need to write an HTTP server yourself, or just use a HTTP framework built on netty.

If you want to build an application using netty, have a look at the examples on https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/